# IOS 7 Approach for create container with two elements?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios7

So, i am new to xcode and iOS7 and i'm trying to create simple container with two elements inside.

1. I prefer to make it 100% programmatically. (no IB)
2. I want to create container with two elements Image and Label.
3. I want to achieve variable width depends on the text element inside.
   Here is example:

[image]

Based on user action i want to change text on the fly. Let's assume longer text, and main container have to change width too.

And now the question is: What is best approach to to that?

UIView with subviews or something else i'm just expecting direction.

Code examples with be gratefully appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The best approach is IB. It generates serialized objects, not code. Anything other than using IB is *not* the best approach. I suggest learning how to use IB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have described is exactly what a UIButton does automatically: it is a container containing an image and a title (text) and it resizes itself automatically when the text changes.

Let us assume, however, that you want to do this yourself. That is, let's say you want a UIView ("container") containing two other UIViews (subviews). Then we need to discuss this requirement:

> Based on user action i want to change text on the fly. Let's assume longer text, and main container have to change width too.

This is not going to happen automatically. You can use constraints (auto layout) to describe the size / position of the subviews in relation to the superview, but it works the other way: the superview changes, and the subviews obey. So you will have to change the superview size *manually* after you change the text.

You can still use auto layout to help you. Let's say the text is in a UILabel. Well, a UILabel wants to change width automatically when the text changes. So far so good. But you must still change the container view width yourself. You can call `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:` to learn what the size of the container *should* be, using constraints, working from the inside out; but then you will have to change its size yourself to that size.

(You can easily create the view, the subviews, and the auto layout constraints in code.)

If you *don't* want to use autolayout, then you will just calculate the sizes and positions of everything when the text changes and adjust it all yourself (in code). You can learn the size the label needs to be, to fit its text, by calling `sizeThatFits:` (or `sizeToFit` which will actually resize it correctly).

Comment: Just wanted to add that a downside to using a UIButton is that the title label will be underlined if the user has "Button Shapes" enabled in their accessibility settings. If the view the OP wants to create is not performing any action when tapped then this can be an unwanted side effect.

Comment: @sooper Very interesting new side effect of using UIButton. I can't decide if I love this feature (make buttons look like buttons) or hate it (mess up my interface).

Comment: Hey @matt! Thanks for your answer. Finally i've made some tests and UIButton actually fit my need! Until your answer i did not know that.

Comment: @OlegPopov I shouldn't have told you - you took the "easy way out"! :))))